# Перенос строки по спецсимволу пробела

Tags: css

Подскажите, можно ли перенести строку по спецсимволу неразрывного пробела '&nbsp' ?
https://jsfiddle.net/2uarzpgx/

```css
   div {
   width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    some text&nbspsome text
</div>
```

Comment: он на то и неразрывный, чтобы не разрывалась строка по нему.